# How to pass function to a child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is where my code is at : https://codesandbox.io/embed/elegant-flower-ouoe1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I have a component called Draggable. I want this component to contain all the logic for dragging its child component. But I want the child component to have a button to start and end the drag. How do I pass my child component a function to do this. At the moment the child component can be dragged, but you can start the drag from anywhere. I want it so you must drag it from the red circle (see in the code).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the function as a props to the children:

```js
  const dragStart = () => {
    // TODO
  }

  return <MyComponent onDragStart={dragStart}/>
```

So your logic will be in the parent in the `dragStart` function and the children can consume it using `props.onDragStart()`

Comment: If I make Draggable return MyComponent, then I could only use Draggable with that. I want to be able to use Draggable with any component. So whenever I include it in my code, its children can get a function to start the drag.

Comment: In this case you can use `React.Context`. Just have a look here https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html